# Attempting to create a WebLogic Domain, fails

Tags: weblogic

I have stood up a WebLogic server. I'm trying to create a basic domain so I can access the admin console.

I run `wlst.sh`, and I run the following:

```
execfile('/opt/oracle/products/Middleware/wlserver/common/templates/scripts/wlst/basicWLSDomain.py')
```

This errors out with the following:

> Error: writeDomain() failed. Do dumpStack() to see details.
>
> Exiting WebLogic Scripting Tool.

Looking at the `basicWLSDomain.py` file, I see the call `writeDomain()` is as follows:

```
writeDomain('/opt/oracle/products/Middleware/user_projects/domains/basicWLSDomain')
```

But WLST exits before I can run `dumpStack()`, so I'm unable to grab the stack trace to see exactly what is happening.

Is there any trick to this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: It's worth noting that the `user_projects` directory didn't exist. I originally thought that was the problem with `writeDomain()`, but I created this directory and the `domains` sub directory but it still failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find a resolution to this.

First off, to prevent WLST from exiting, I had to comment out the last line of `basicWLSDomain.py` on the `exit()` call. Then WSLT didn't exit after the script completed.

Running `dumpStack()` showed that the password wasn't set for the weblogic user.

In the `Define the user password for weblogic.` section, adding the line `cmo.setPassword('...')` resolved this.